# nodemon stuck at ''restarting due to changes..." for some reason

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

nodemon doesn't restart after any changes I do. currently, there is no difference between nodemon and node command

```
console.log('one')
```

if I use nodemon command and change 'one' to 'two' i get  "restarting due to changes..." and nothing happens after that

this is my package.json file

```
{
 "name": "weather_app",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "main": "app.js",
 "scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
"connect-livereload": "^0.6.1",
"handlebars": "^4.7.7",
"hbs": "^4.1.2",
"livereload": "^0.9.3",
"nodemon": "^2.0.12"
}
}
```

this problem started after I formatted my pc but, I don't think that's the reason
if you could help me I would be very grateful

Comment: how do you run `nodemon` what is the full command you typed ?

Comment: nodemon file.js

Comment: Add the watch flag `nodemon --watch file.js`

Comment: now i get this on the terminal:Usage: nodemon [nodemon options] [script.js] [args]

  See "nodemon --help" for more.

Comment: i just downgraded the nodemon and it worked finally. thank you for your help <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed this problem by downgrading nodemon to 2.0.2
you can do that by uninstalling the package and installing it again

```
npm uninstall nodemon
```

then

```
npm i nodemon@2.0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh my god, I am gonna kill myself.

After installing nodemon I was trying to run this

```
npm start
```

And it is actually should be

```
nodemon index.js
```